# How to get an EXACT Character in a CharSequence?

Tags: java, android, charsequence

I want to extract only the exact character in a **CharSequence** when I know the position (or key) of the character in it!

`For eg: In the CharSequence "HELLO" I want to Extract the letter in the position 2 which is "E" in this case` . *How can I do that?*

**TO BE MORE SPECIFIC:**
I am building an Android application where I am using the TextWatcher to obtain the text entered by people in the TextEdit field as follows.

```
    EditText KeyLogEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextforKeyLog);
    KeyLogEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Here is where I need help!!
            // I have the "start" and "before" keys I have the position of the character inserted
            // I need to obtain the EXACT character from the CharSequence "s", How do I Do that?                

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

My Question is commented within the code as well.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.
Adit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [the `charAt()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html#charAt%28int%29) on `CharSequence`.

Comment: Probably needing `length()` too. Zero-based indexing of the sequence, so E in HELLO is charAt(1).

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

           // the EXACT character from the CharSequence "s"
         
            int lastIndex = s.length() - 1;
            char lastChar = s.charAt(lastIndex);
            String lastStr = Character.toString(lastChar);

            EditText.setText(lastStr);
```

}